# iOS 5, Storyboards,ARC: Creating and setting custom delegate and datasource to program. created UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

The prequel of this problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042770/ios-5-storyboards-customize-programmatically-created-uitableview-for-every-uiv).

I am trying to create and set a custom delegate and datasource to my programmatically created UITableView. I've googled around, but couldn't find any clear solution for my problem.

Meanwhile, I've created a new class that conforms to UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
protocols. In this class:

tableView numberOfRowsInSection: 20
tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: cell.textLabel.text=@"Nominals";

Class that contains UIViews:

Method that creates UITableView:

```
-(IBAction)segmentValueChaged:(id)sender
{
if(self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
{
    [self.coinageView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:nominalsView];
    [self populateNominals:self.subCountryID];
}
else 
{
    [self.nominalsView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:coinageView];
    [self populateCoinages:self.subCountryID];
}
}

-(void)populateNominals:(int)subCountryID
{
NominalsTableViewDelegate *del=[[NominalsTableViewDelegate alloc]init];
UITableView *nominalsTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 372) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[nominalsTableView setDelegate:del];
[nominalsTableView setDataSource:del];
[self.nominalsView addSubview:nominalsTableView];
[nominalsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Finally, I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
The evil is in [nominalsTableView setDelegate:del]; [nominalsTableView setDataSource:del]; rows. What's wrong with them.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are adding a new UITableView to your current view or not, but I will assume you are doing so.

If you have a class that conforms to the UITableViewDelegate. But when i needed to create a UITableView programmatically, I create a new UITableView class (with the .h and .m) then make a MutableArray and exposing it as a property to the parent view so it can set the data source.

From there, you can create an instance of the class along with the datasource (which you exposed from the child object). Finally, you then add the view onto your current view. This method you dont need to set the delegate because your child class conforms to the tableview delegate protocol.

If you are just modifying the data inside the current tableview then, you use a `NSMutableArray` and then change the data in it. After then do a

```
      [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this helps!

**EDITED**

I might have misunderstood your question, what you (most likely) need to do is create a property of the delegate class then create an instance of your delgate class and assign it to the property.

Then do a

```
      [myTableView setDelegate:self.myProperty];
      [myTableView setDatasource:self.myProperty];
```

This, I believe, would solve you bad access problem.

**EDITED AGAIN**

Create a property inside your .h of the tableview class as such:

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NominalsTableViewDelegate *myDelegate;
```

From there then inside your .m file, you do something similar to this:

```
NominalsTableViewDelegate* delegateClass = [[NominalsTableViewDelegate alloc] init];
[self setMyDelegate:delegateClass];
[delegateClass release];
```

Then you can set your tableview datasource as such:

```
[myTableView setDelegate:self.myDelegate];
[myTableView setDatasource:self.myDelegate];
```

***Note***: I currently have no access to a machine to test this, but just something to point you towards.

Comment: Meanwhile I am just trying to output word nominals 20 times... There's no need of any array, but you gave me an idea. Thanks

Comment: um, ok so you commented while i was editing the answer, but hope the edit helps!

Comment: Can you remind me how to create a property of the delegate class then create an instance of your delgate class and assign it to the property? Is the something like id del < NominalsTableViewDelegate>...

Comment: Well, now it's doesn't crash, but also doesn't populate the tableview. Doesn't my table view suppose to fill 20 cells with the text. Just a moment I'll update my question...

Comment: Ok. It's another question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad i could help. Finally, you might want to look at these 2 tutorial on custom delegate. They are not for UITableView, but you can get the idea at least.    http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/    http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/058-Delegates.pl