# iOS 5, Storyboards, ARC: UITableview doesn't get populated with data from custom delegate and datasource

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

This is my first time I am working on UITableView connected to custom delegate and datasource. Until today, I used to connect to "self". The prequel for this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059235/ios-5-storyboards-arc-creating-and-setting-custom-delegate-and-datasource-to-p).

So, I have two additional UIViews. Using segmented control I put one of the over mentioned UIViews on self.view...

Have created two UITableView subclasses and set them as delegate and datasource. Works fine, no leaks or crashes. Checked if the classes getting initialized on segmentedControl index change:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    NSLog(@"Nominals got init");
}
return self;
}
```

NSLog works when changing segment.

The question:

In my custom delegate class I override the methods required by UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 12, 200, 12)];
lbl.text=@"some nominal";
cell.textLabel.text=@"Nominal";
[cell addSubview:lbl];

return cell;
}
```

At moment I am getting exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Well, isn't the cell in my custom delegated class is the same cell of my UITableView I've created:

```
-(void)populateNominals:(int)subCountryID
{
NominalsTableViewDelegate *del=[[NominalsTableViewDelegate alloc]init];
[self setNominalsDelegate:del];


UITableView *nominalsTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 372) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

[nominalsTableView setDelegate:nominalsDelegate];
[nominalsTableView setDataSource:nominalsDelegate];
[nominalsTableView reloadData];
[self.nominalsView addSubview:nominalsTableView];

}
```

what's my mistake? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aretrying to `dequeue` a `cell` using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. If there is no `cell` in the queue what happens ? Definitely crash.

So you need to allocate a cell, add this line too:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Yes. Storyboards guarantee that cell is available and there's no need to check. Now I am kind of out of storyboard. Another lesson.

Answer (score 1):

On your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, you are missing the case where there are no cells to be dequeued. Take a look at your code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 12, 200, 12)];
    lbl.text=@"some nominal";
    cell.textLabel.text=@"Nominal";
    [cell addSubview:lbl];

    return cell;
}
```

You should do something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 12, 200, 12)];
    lbl.text=@"some nominal";
    cell.textLabel.text=@"Nominal";
    [cell addSubview:lbl];

    return cell;
}
```

because by doing that, if you can't dequeue a cell, you're creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will return UITableViewCell instances when the cells are being reused while scrolling through the tableView.

So add

```
if (nil == cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

You have to use the initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: which is the designated initializer for tableview cells.