# iOS 5, Storyboards, ARC: Navigation Controller doesn't work in custom delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

The prequel for this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059235/ios-5-storyboards-arc-creating-and-setting-custom-delegate-and-datasource-to-p). Now I've got another problem. I cannot navigate despite of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath getting invoked while tapping on cell

```
KMList *detailViewController = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"KMs"];
detailViewController.fromPeriod=self.fromPeriod;
detailViewController.period1=self.entityID;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

What the problem. Is it because I am kind of off the storyboard?

P.S No warnings or errors. Just nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is self? Where is this code running? In particular, use logging to confirm that self.navigationController is what you expect; if it's nil, for example, you'll get no warning and no error but nothing will happen.

Comment: NominalsTableViewDelegate : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> so I expect it to be not nil.

Comment: if(!self.navigationController)
    {
        NSLog(@"nil");
    }
says nil.

Comment: Should I create an additional navigation controller and assign to this additional controller the value of controller where the custom UITableViews were created?

Comment: Made it. Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x8a99240>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not push the new view controller in code when using a storyboard. This is done automatically. Instead make a push-Segue in Interface Builder and give it an identifier. Then in your view controller you overwrite `prepareForSegue:sender:` and check for the identifier like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"<your segue identifier>"]) {
        KMList *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.fromPeriod=self.fromPeriod;
        detailViewController.period1=self.entityID;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right but maybe you should drag out the segue directly from the view controller instead of the table view. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you then simply call `performSegue:withIdentifier:`.

Comment: (<NominalsTableViewDelegate: 0x7f583b0>) has no segue with identifier 'toKMList'' Because this is custom UITableView delegate and datasource. It's not connected to anybody on storyboards.

Comment: The delegate is connected to tableViews that getting created programmatically on runtime.